# BioPython: Amino acid Sequence contains 'J' and can't calculate the molecular weight

Tags: python, bioinformatics, xlrd, biopython

The data which I am working with comes in an Excel file which has the amino acid sequence on index 1. I'm trying to calculate different attributes based on the sequence using BioPython. The code which I have now:

```
import xlrd
import sys
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis

print '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ EXCEL PARSER FOR PVA/NON-PVA DATA ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'

print 'Path to Excel file:', str(sys.argv[1])
fname = sys.argv[1]
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname, 'rU')

print ''
print 'The sheet names that have been found in the Excel file: '
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
number_of_sheet = 1
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    print '*', number_of_sheet, ':     ', sheet_name
    number_of_sheet += 1

with open("thefile.txt","w") as f:
    lines = []
    f.write('LENGTH.SEQUENCE,SEQUENCE,MOLECULAR.WEIGHT\n')
    for sheet_name in sheet_names:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        print 'opened: ', sheet_name
        for i in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
            row = worksheet.row_values(i)
            analysed_seq = ProteinAnalysis(row[1].encode('utf-8'))
            weight = analysed_seq.molecular_weight()
            lines.append('{},{},{}\n'.format(row[2], row[1].encode('utf-8'), weight))
    f.writelines(lines)
```

It was working up until I added the calculation of the molecular weight. This showed that the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Excel_PVAdata_Parser.py", line 28, in <module>
    weight = analysed_seq.molecular_weight()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/SeqUtils/ProtParam.py", line 114, in molecular_weight
    total_weight += aa_weights[aa]
KeyError: 'J'
```

I looked in the Excel data file and this shows that the amino acid sequence does contain a J. Does someone know a package of BioPython which catches there 'unknown aminoacids' or have another suggestion?

Comment: This problem seems to be very much package specific, and this isn't any python standard module. I'd suggest to look into a specific forum or in the project's github page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [peterjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344850/peterjc) said, `J` is an ambiguous amino acid coding for either leucine (`L`) or isoleucine (`I`). Both have the same molecular weight:

```
>>> from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis
>>> ProteinAnalysis('L').molecular_weight()
131.1729
>>> ProteinAnalysis('I').molecular_weight()
131.1729
```

So you could temporarily replace all occurrences of `J` with either `L` or `I` for calculating the molecular weight.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will write an function to validate the sequence and change the J when it occurs into a L.

Comment: I should have checked that, well spotted. It would seem reasonable for Biopython to do this for ``J`` without user-intervention. Do you fancy making a pull request or filing an issue?

Answer (score 3):

Biopython is using the protein molecular weights from IUPAC, see https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Data/IUPACData.py

J is an ambiguous amino acid coding for either leucine or isoleucine (L or I), and is used in NMR where it is not possible to tell these apart.

Depending on why you need the molecular weight, it might be appropriate for you to use the mean of the weight using L and I?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will write an function to validate the sequence and change the J when it occurs into a L.